# torch.unique does not work for float tensors

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to extract the unique elements from a float tensor.
I have tried :

```
out = torch.unique(my_tensor)
```

However this method only works for int/long tensor. My tensor is quantizied tensor in a non-uniform way, thus its guaranteed to have a small set of float values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could using `numpy.unique` instead

```
import torch
import numpy as np

t = torch.tensor([1.05, 1.05, 2.01, 2.01, 3.9, 3.9001])
print(np.unique(t.numpy()))
```

Outputs:

```
[1.05   2.01   3.9    3.9001]
```